# SQL Help - Detect Changes Within Specified List of Values

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I need to create a report that returns customer accounts whose account type have changed to or from this list of account_types:
('CAM','CAMADP','CAMHD','CAMHDADP','DIST','DISTADP','GAM','GAMADP','LAM','LAMADP').

Let's say I have this table today:

| client | account_type | customer_org_ID | insert_date | update_date | active_Y_N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google | GAM | C000001 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | 2020-05-04 06:01:16 | Y |
| Netflix | LAM | C000002 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | 2021-09-04 08:35:34 | Y |
| Nordstrom | DIST | C000003 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | 2021-05-04 02:15:34 | Y |
| Costco | CAMHDADP | C000004 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | 2021-05-04 09:36:34 | Y |
| Boeing | CAMHD | C000005 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | 2021-05-04 12:15:45 | Y |
| Samsung | DISTADP | C000006 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | 2020-06-15 01:10:16 | Y |

Let's say I come into work tomorrow and there have been changes to rows 1, 2, 3, 5, and 6 (seen in bold).

| client | account_type | customer_org_ID | insert_date | update_date | active_Y_N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google | **CAM** | C000001 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | **2021-11-03 12:40:41** | Y |
| Netflix | **DISTADP** | C000002 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | **2021-11-03 12:40:41** | Y |
| Nordstrom | **GAMADP** | C000003 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | **2021-11-03 12:40:41** | Y |
| Costco | CAMHDADP | C000004 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | 2021-05-04 09:36:34 | Y |
| Boeing | **UNKWN** | C000005 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | **2021-11-03 12:40:41** | Y |
| Samsung | DISTADP | C000006 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | **2021-11-03 12:40:41** | **N** |

I need a sql query that will return these three rows of data since there were updates made to their account_type within the list of account_types that I mentioned in the beginning.

| client | account_type | customer_org_ID | insert_date | update_date | active_Y_N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google | CAM | C000001 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | 2021-11-03 12:40:41 | Y |
| Netflix | DISTADP | C000002 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | 2021-11-03 12:40:41 | Y |
| Nordstrom | GAMADP | C000003 | 2006-05-04 09:15:34 | 2021-11-03 12:40:41 | Y |

I am working in DB2 LUW database.

Comment: For something like this you may need to use an archive table with a trigger that records the changes.

Comment: "you would know by checking if `update_date` is a recent date" -- so why can't you check it?

Comment: @mustaccio Because in my database there are a lot more columns than just the 3 I listed in my question. Other columns include address, contact info, active or inactive, etc. This means that a recent update_date doesn't mean the account_type was updated. It could be the customer's contact info that changed or their address, etc.

Comment: So, is this a question on how to add to this table another timestamp column and create a `before update of (account_type)` trigger updating this column, when new and old values of `account_type` are not equal and at least one of them is in the list you provided above?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Please see updated post...

Comment: Again, you need to create a trigger on this table and add either a new timestamp column to this table or a new table. The latter is possible, if you have a unique index on the base table (please, specify it if so). Which approach would you like to implement?

Comment: I don't have a unique index on the base table unfortunately so I'd like to implement the approach that doesn't require this..which is the trigger + the new timestamp column I believe.. @MarkBarinstein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this changing `mytab` to your real table name.

```
ALTER TABLE mytab ADD UPDATE_AT_DATE TIMESTAMP;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytab_BUR
BEFORE UPDATE OF ACCOUNT_TYPE ON mytab
REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN 
(
--     O.ACCOUNT_TYPE IS DISTINCT FROM N.ACCOUNT_TYPE
--  AND
--  (
     O.ACCOUNT_TYPE IN ('CAM','CAMADP','CAMHD','CAMHDADP','DIST','DISTADP','GAM','GAMADP','LAM','LAMADP')
  OR N.ACCOUNT_TYPE IN ('CAM','CAMADP','CAMHD','CAMHDADP','DIST','DISTADP','GAM','GAMADP','LAM','LAMADP')
--  )
)
SET N.UPDATE_AT_DATE = CURRENT TIMESTAMP 
;
```

You may uncomment the commented out lines, if your applications may update the `ACCOUNT_TYPE` column with the same value as it already has, and you don't want to update the new `UPDATE_AT_DATE` column value in such cases.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

DB2 offre temporal tables feature, it was introduced since the version 10.

no need to use trigger, DB2 manage this automatically

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=tables-system-period-temporal

https://philipkgunning.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/traveling-through-time-with-db2-time-travel-query3apr13.pdf